# rxjs function not running

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs

I am trying to wait for a function to run in async context in rxjs, but I cannot get the function to run:

```js
export async function scan(options: TaskOptions) {
  console.log("running scan");
  await setTimeout(5000);

  return true;
}

export const queue$ = new Subject<TaskOptions>();
const scanTasks$ = new Subject<TaskOptions>();

export const scanResult$ = scanTasks$.pipe(
  switchMap((options) =>
    // Doesn't run
    from(scan(options)).pipe(
      map(() => ({ error: undefined, success: true })),
      catchError((error: Error) => of({ error, success: false }))
    )
  )
);

queue$.subscribe((options) => {
  console.log("queue subscribe"); // runs
  scanTasks$.next(options);
});

// async context
queue$.next(options)

await firstValueFrom(scanResult$)
```

I also tried to add .subscribe to the end of the pipe at scanResult$. What would be the proper way to get the function to run

Comment: Move the `firstValueFrom` before you emit on the `queue`. Right now you are subscribing to the `scanResult$` observable **after** the queue notification is already  emitted so you are missing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using 'defer' instead of 'from' to handle the asynchronous nature of the scan function, as 'from' is typically employed for converting observables into iterables or promises. defer is better suited for handling asynchronous functions that return promises.

```
  export async function scan(options: 
  TaskOptions) 
  {
  console.log("running scan");
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 
  5000)); 
  return true;
  } 

  export const queue$ = new Subject<TaskOptions>.();
  const scanTasks$ = new Subject<TaskOptions>();

  export const scanResult$ = scanTasks$.pipe(
  switchMap((options) =>
  defer(() => from(scan(options))).pipe(
  // The scan function will now be executed
  map(() => ({ error: undefined, success: true 
  })),
  catchError((error: Error) => of({ error, 
   success: false }))
  ))
  );

  queue$.subscribe((options) => {
  console.log("queue subscribe"); // runs
  scanTasks$.next(options);
  });

  // Simulate an event in an async context
  (async () => {
  queue$.next(options);
  const result = await 
  firstValueFrom(scanResult$);
  console.log(result);
  })();
```

Instead of using from(scan(options)), use defer(() => from(scan(options))). Deferring makes sure that every time a new item is emitted on scanTasks$, the scan function is called.

Instead to using await setTimeout(5000);, use await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));. SetTimeout provides a timer ID, not a promise, hence the await keyword should be used in conjunction with a promise. In an asynchronous context, it functions correctly when encapsulated in a Promise.

Comment: I imported `import { setTimeout } from "node:timers/promises";`, it does not seem to run with defer in your example however

Comment: I see Its an error from my end. If you're using setTimeout from "node:timers/promises", you don't need to wrap it in a Promise because it already returns a promise. So, you can simplify that part:

Comment: so we can keep your code at that place 

export async function scan(options: TaskOptions) {
  console.log("running scan");
  await setTimeout(5000);
  return true;
}